# How to add images to parquet table in Python?

Tags: python, parquet, pyarrow

I need to open images from a folder and add them to a parquet file. I cannot find any code to define the data type as an image and when I try this, I get an error:

```
with Image.open("Frame 205.png") as im:
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Images': [im, im, im],
                   'Description': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']},
                   index=list('abc'))
    table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
```

Error

ArrowInvalid: ('Could not convert <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=390x390 at 0x2A93E2B50> with type PngImageFile: did not recognize Python value type when inferring an Arrow data type', 'Conversion failed for column Images with type object')

How do I fix this?

I saw some people suggesting converting the image using numpy but then when I download the parquet, won't it be a string?

Answer (score 0):

With arrow table (and parquet files), you have to store records using primitive types (int, string...) or more complex data structure (nested struct, map, list...).

But you can't store any arbitrary python object (eg: `PIL.Image`).

So the solution would be to extract the relevant data and metadata from the image and put it in a table:

```py
import pyarrow as pa
import PIL

file_names = ["./image.png"]
records = []
for file_name in file_names:
    with PIL.Image.open(file_name) as im:
        records.append({
            "file_name": file_name,
            "height": im.height,
            "widgth": im.width,
            "bytes": im.tobytes()
        })

table = pa.Table.from_pylist(records)
```

Exactly what metadata and how to represent the data of the image depends on your use case (eg: do you want raw images or compressed image...).